# Angular material table not updating with change in datasource - filtering done from spring backend

Tags: java, angular, spring, rendering, angular-material-table

Angular table data not updating. Only updates when I switch component and come back to the table component.

Tried using this.table.renderRows() but getting table object is undefined.

Below is the code - there are 3 Ts classes which are extending base main and filter class.

```
import { Directive, Injector, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {BaseComponent} from "./base.component";
import {take, takeUntil} from "rxjs/operators";
import {ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {PaginatedCollection} from "./shared/models/dto/paginated-collection";
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material/table";
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

@Directive()
export abstract class BaseCollectionComponent<T> extends BaseComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T>;
  public collection: PaginatedCollection<T>;
  public currentPage: number;
  public pageSize: number;

  protected searchString: string;

  public counter: number = 0;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  readonly route: ActivatedRoute;
  readonly router: Router;

  protected constructor(injector: Injector, public ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super();
    this.route = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    this.router = injector.get(Router);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fillTable();
  }

  fillTable(){
    this.route.queryParams
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        const page = params['page'] ? +params['page'] : 1;
        this.pageSize = params['size'] ? +params['size'] : 15;
        this.searchString = params['s'] ? params['s'] : null;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.setPage(page);
        //setInterval(() => this.setPage(page), 3000);
      });
  }

  protected abstract fetch(): Observable<PaginatedCollection<T>>

  public search(searchString: string) {
    if (this.searchString !== searchString) {
      this.searchString = searchString;
      this.setPage(1);
    }
  }

  public searchReset(): void {
    this.searchString = null;
    this.setPage(1);
  }

  public setPageSize(size: number): void {
    this.pageSize = size;
    this.setPage(1);
  }

  public setPage(page: number): void {
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.fetch()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        (res: PaginatedCollection<T>) => {
          this.handleSuccess(res);
          this.ref.detectChanges();},
        (error: string) => this.handleError(error)
      );
  }

  protected deleteSuccess(id: string, msg: string): void {
    this.setSuccessMessage(msg);
    this.collection.items = this.collection.items
      .filter((item: any) => item.id !== id);
  }

   handleSuccess(collection: PaginatedCollection<T>): void {
    this.collection = collection;
    this.dataSource.data = this.collection.items;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.setQueryParamsInUrl();
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
  }

  private setQueryParamsInUrl(): void {
    const queryParams = {
      page: this.currentPage,
      size: this.pageSize
    };

    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
  }


}
```

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Injector, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TransactionService} from "../../shared/services/transaction.service";
import {BaseCollectionComponent} from "../../base.collection.component";
import {Transaction} from "../../shared/models/entity/transaction";
import {PaginatedCollection} from "../../shared/models/dto/paginated-collection";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.scss']
})
export class TransactionsComponent extends BaseCollectionComponent<Transaction> {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['webshopOrderNumber', 'lastModified', 'state', 'paymentMethod', 'monetaryData.discount', 'monetaryData.grandTotalGross', 'monetaryData.applicationFeeIncl', 'details', 'actions' ];  
  enabled: boolean = true;

  @ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<any>;


  constructor(
    private transactionService: TransactionService,
    injector: Injector,
    ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    super(injector, ref);
  }
  
  updateTable(){
   // this.dataSource.data = [];
   this.fillTable();
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.collection.items);
   this.table.renderRows();
  }

  protected fetch(): Observable<PaginatedCollection<Transaction>> {
    return this.transactionService.getTransactionsWithFilters(this.currentPage, this.pageSize, this.transactionService.filters);
  }
}
```

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Injector, Input, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { TransactionService } from '../../services/transaction.service';
import { TransactionsComponent } from 'src/app/content/transactions/transactions.component';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TransactionState } from '../../models/entity/enum/transaction-state';
import { PaymentMethod } from '../../models/entity/enum/payment-method';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.scss']
})
export class FilterComponent extends TransactionsComponent{

  @Input() visible: boolean;

  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(null),
    end: new FormControl(null),
    state: new FormControl(null),
    method: new FormControl(null),
    order: new FormControl(null)
  });

  states = Object.keys(TransactionState);
  paymentMethods = Object.keys(PaymentMethod);
  order:String;

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private service: TransactionService, public datepipe: DatePipe, ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(service, injector, ref);
  }

  filter(){
    if(this.range.value.end != null){
    this.service.filters.toDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.range.value.end, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }
    if(this.range.value.start != null){
    this.service.filters.fromDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.range.value.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }
    if(this.range.value.state != null){
    this.service.filters.transactionState = this.range.value.state;
    }
    if(this.range.value.method != null){
      this.service.filters.usedPaymentMethod = this.range.value.method;
    }
    if(this.range.value.order != null){
      this.service.filters.webshopOrderNumber = this.range.value.order;
    }
    this.updateTable();
  }

  clearFilters(){
    this.service.filters.fromDate = null;
    this.service.filters.toDate = null;
    this.service.filters.transactionState = null;
    this.service.filters.usedPaymentMethod = null;
    this.service.filters.webshopOrderNumber = null;
    this.range.reset();
    this.updateTable();
  }
```

This is the html with table belonging to the Transaction component

```
<section class="content-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.title' | translate}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<app-message-display [error]="error"></app-message-display>


<section class="mat-elevation-z8" class="content mb-5" *ngIf="collection">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="card-tools">
            <app-page-size [id]="'page-size-changer'" (sizeChanged)="setPageSize($event)"></app-page-size>
          </div>
          <div>
            <table #table table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="webshopOrderNumber">
                <th style="width: 10%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><a
                    class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.order-number' | translate}}</a>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><a class="link-primary"
                    [routerLink]="['/transactions', row.id]">{{row.webshopOrderNumber | translate}}</a></td>
                <ng-template #noWebshopId>
                  <td>-</td>
                </ng-template>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="lastModified">
                <th style="width: 10%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><a
                    class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.transaction-date' |
                    translate}}</a></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.lastModified |
                  date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
                <th style="width: 15%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><a
                    class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.state' | translate}}</a></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{'ENUM.TRANSACTION-STATE.' +
                  row.state | translate}}</td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="paymentMethod">
                <th style="width: 15%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                  <a class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.payment-method' | translate}}</a>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{'ENUM.PAYMENT-METHOD.' +
                  (row.paymentMethod | uppercase) | translate}}</td>
                <ng-template #noPaymentMethod>
                  <td>-</td>
                </ng-template>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="monetaryData.discount">
                <th style="width: 10%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><a
                    class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.discount' | translate}}</a></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.monetaryData.discount |
                  currency:'EUR'}}</td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="monetaryData.grandTotalGross">
                <th style="width: 10%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><a
                    class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.total' | translate}}</a></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                  {{row.monetaryData.grandTotalGross |
                  currency:'EUR'}}</td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="monetaryData.applicationFeeIncl">
                <th style="width: 15%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><a
                    class="hover header-text">{{'COMPONENTS.TRANSACTIONS.app-fee' | translate}}</a></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                  {{row.monetaryData.applicationFeeIncl | currency:'EUR'}}</td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="details">
                <th style="width: 10%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                  {{'COMMON.details' | translate}}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <a class="link-primary"
                    [routerLink]="['/transactions', row.id]">{{'COMMON.view-details' | translate}}</a></td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <th style="width: 20%" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-right pr-5">
                  {{'COMMON.actions' | translate}}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="text-right pr-2">
                  <div class="btn-group" dropdown [autoClose]="true" [isAnimated]="true" [insideClick]="false">
                    <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
                      {{'COMMON.actions' | translate}} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu"
                      aria-labelledby="button-basic">
                      <!-- <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/transactions', transaction.id]">{{'COMMON.view-details' | translate}}</a>
            </li> -->
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </ng-container>


              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

              <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
              <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                <td class="mat-cell" colspan="8">No data matching the filter</td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <div class="card-footer">
              <app-pagination (pageChange)="setPage($event)" [collection]="collection"
                class="justify-content-center"></app-pagination>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the console output

```
[Info] Successfully preconnected to https://fonts.gstatic.com/
[Warning] Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming (vendor.js, line 68622)
[Log] Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode. (vendor.js, line 55406)
[Info] [WDS] Live Reloading enabled. (vendor.js, line 112493)
[Log] Array (15) (main.js, line 327)
[Log] Array (15) (main.js, line 327)
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.table.renderRows')
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.table.renderRows')
    defaultErrorLogger (vendor.js:33845)
    handleError (vendor.js:33893)
    handleError (vendor.js:38304)
    executeListenerWithErrorHandling (vendor.js:42677)
    wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (vendor.js:42712)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:81271)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.js:56026)
    runTask (polyfills.js:187)
    invokeTask (polyfills.js:496)
    invokeTask (polyfills.js:1609)
    globalZoneAwareCallback (polyfills.js:1635)
[Log] Array (15) (main.js, line 327)
[Log] Array (15) (main.js, line 327)
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.table.renderRows')
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.table.renderRows')
    defaultErrorLogger (vendor.js:33845)
    handleError (vendor.js:33893)
    handleError (vendor.js:38304)
    executeListenerWithErrorHandling (vendor.js:42677)
    wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (vendor.js:42712)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:81271)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.js:56026)
    runTask (polyfills.js:187)
    invokeTask (polyfills.js:496)
    invokeTask (polyfills.js:1609)
    globalZoneAwareCallback (polyfills.js:1635)
[Log] Array (15) (main.js, line 327)
[Log] Array (15) (main.js, line 327)
> Selected Element
< <td _ngcontent-djc-c128 role="cell" mat-cell class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-webshopOrderNumber mat-column-webshopOrderNumber ng-star-inserted">…</td>
```